# I got stuck on this exercise can't figure the True/False part

Tags: python

I got some homework to do and I got stuck with this code. I have no idea how to continue.
This is what I'm suppose to do:

> 1. `generate_sequence` - Will generate a list of random numbers between 1 to 101. The list
>      length will be difficulty.
> 2. `get_list_from_user` - Will return a list of numbers prompted from the user. The list length
>      will be in the size of difficulty.
> 3. `is_list_equal` - A function to compare two lists if they are equal. The function will return
>      True / False.
> 4. `play` - Will call the functions above and play the game. Will return True / False if the user
>      lost or won.

(Sorry for copy/pasting. My English is not so good.)

```
import random

difficulty = 101
secret_number = 6

def generate_number():
    global secret_number
    secret_number = random.randint(0, difficulty)

def get_guess_from_user():
    return input( "Please choose number between 1 to " + str(difficulty))

def compare_results(userInput):
    isSame = False
    if(secret_number == userInput):
        isSame = True

    return isSame

def play():
    generate_number()
    userInput = get_guess_from_user()
    isSame = compare_results(userInput)
    print("number generated is: " + str(secret_number))
    print(isSame)

play()
```

Comment: So, you've done this "game" to work with single number and want to let it work with sequence?

Comment: sorry,i edited it now

Comment: Do you want the program to generate, say 10 numbers, and check to see if all those 10 numbers are exactly what the user inputs?

Comment: basicaly what i need is a number to be shown for a few seconds to the user and then let user guess the number through input

Answer (score 1):

Your "problem" is, that `if(secret_number == userInput):` is currently comparing an `int` to a `str`, because the result of `input()` is always a `str`, even if the input is numeric. An `int` and a `str` are never equal, thus `isSame` will always be `False`.

You have to cast the user input to `int` somewhere along the way before or during the comparison.

e.g.:

```
def get_guess_from_user():
    return int(input( "Please choose number between 1 to " + str(difficulty)))
    #      ^^^
```

Otherwise, your program seems to do what you are describing.

You could save some lines of code by writing:

```
def compare_results(userInput):
    return (secret_number == userInput)
```

---

I took the liberty to rewrite your application w/o global variables:

```
import random

def generate_number(difficulty):
    return random.randint(1, difficulty)

def get_guess_from_user(difficulty):
    return int(input( "Please choose number between 1 to {}".format(difficulty)))

def play(difficulty):
    secret_number = generate_number(difficulty)
    user_input = get_guess_from_user(difficulty)
    is_same = (secret_number == user_input)
    print("number generated is: {}".format(secret_number))
    print("Your guess was {}".format( "correct :)" if is_same else "not correct :(" ))

play(5)
```

Note: I also changed `random.randint(0, difficulty)` to `random.randint(1, difficulty)`, because the lower part is also inclusive, meaning that it could return `0`. When prompting the user for a number between `1 and 5`, the user might be surprised that the correct number was `0` instead.

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.randint):

> random.randint(a, b)
>
> > Return a random integer N such that `a <= N <= b`. Alias for `randrange(a, b+1)`.

Comment: wow,you like cut my code in half.amazing! and what if i want to create a secret number that would be static and not randomly change? because i want to add a line that shows the user a secret number that will disapear after a few seconds.

Comment: Then I suggest you create the number in advance and pass it as parameter to the functions that need to use it, just like I passed ``5`` as ``difficulty`` to the various functions. Another step could be to re-write your code to use a class and a class instance instead, to further encapsulate the values you're working with (difficulty, secret_number) and the user interaction. If this answer helped with your original question, please consider to accept/upvote it.